# Ubuntu 14.04 latest update Beyond Compare and TortoiseHG issues

Tags: updates, gui, qt

After updating to the latest (as of Nov 1, 2015) Ubuntu 14.04 packages, the UI appears broken on Beyond Compare and TortoiseHG. Most items aren't visible and the when I move the mouse over the window, some UI elements are flickering.
[Beyond Compare screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijQEY.png)

I could identify that they both use Qt 4 so I'm guessing the issue might be with this package.

- bcompare version: 4.1.1-20615
- tortoisehg version: 2.10-1

Comment: I've also seen something similar with Beyond Compare and KeepasX. However the problem disappeared after reboot.

Comment: It didn't disappear after reboot in my case. Rebooting after the latest update (Nov 6, 2015) fixed the issue.

Comment: I've found that the problem was caused by a shared memory leak in java applications: http://askubuntu.com/questions/696323/qt-interfaces-broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears resolved after the update on Nov 6, 2015 and a reboot.