# QT interfaces broken

Tags: 14.04, qt

I ran into a strange issue a couple of days ago and i have no idea what to do. Some of my programs interfaces seem to be broken recently. It is rather odd because i haven't done any major updates. It seems to me (although i'm no expert) that all the QT interfaces are broken (ie VLC, Clementine, Skype). It is really bothering me because i cannot use a lot of programs. However the majority of programs and the system itself are running just fine.

The interfaces appear somehow incomplete with all the components having wrong dimensions, texts not appearing and flickering on user interactions. I really have no idea where to start and what can possibly cause an issue like that as it was working fine for years.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Running some of the programs from command line i get a gtk-warning `Gdk-WARNING **: shmget failed: error 28`. This seems to be because of something with shared memory segments. This is really strange to me as i am kind of using my system the same way i always did. A search on this error brought quite some confusing information. However i couldn't find a solution or any information that was helpful for me.

For skype i have tried the solution & workaround from here without sucess: [How to fix graphical issues with Skype, Gdk-WARNING?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692825/how-to-fix-graphical-issues-with-skype-gdk-warning)

**EDIT:**

I found out the applications work fine when i have a fresh restart. They just stop working at some point... So the `Gdk-WARNING` concerning shared memory seems to be the problem. Although i cannot seem to free any of the memory by closing all my running applications. So probably the solution would be to find the application that is cluttering the shared memory space?

Comment: Have you tried changing the theme?

Comment: Change the theme of what? I tried with individual applications but i cannot see the preferences dialogs cause the elements are mostly missing

Comment: I meant changing the overall system theme from Ambiance (the default) to something else, using the Appearance dialog (in the Dash, search for Appearance) or something like Unity Tweak Tool.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. But i don't really want to change my theme, so that would be the last option. But i have discovered the following which might rule out the theme anyway: The applications work fine when i have a fresh restart. They just stop working at some point... So the `Gdk-WARNING` concerning shared memory seems to be the problem. Although i cannot seem to free any of the memory by closing all my running applications. So probably the solution would be to find the application that is cluttering the shared memory space?

Comment: Same problem for me, started appearing today without any major updates :(

Comment: This might be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469060/python-error-message-in-pycharm-unable-to-attach-to-shared-memory-segment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating my JDK from version 7 to 8 solved the problem for me.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

If you are using 14.04 or older you probably need to manually add a PPA before installing (for example `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa`, no safety guarantee though!)

Next, select the new version via:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java.
```

You can check your java version via:

```
java -version
```

It should print something like `openjdk version "1.8.0_45-internal"`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your post. Actually it really seems to be because of IntelliJ/Android Studio. They say that they have performance issues with OpenJDK, maybe that's what is meant. So far closing Android Studio also seem to work, so no immediate need for me to update jdk.

Comment: Actually problem was in `openjdk-7` version `7u85-2.6.1-5`. Updating to `7u91-2.6.3-1` fix issue without  installing `openjdk-8`. See http://askubuntu.com/a/701642/35474

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. You're right, the reason is there is no free shared memory in the system.

To find out, who's taking all shared memory, you can run `ipcs -m -p`. In my case the output was something like:

```
$ ipcs -m -p

------ Shared Memory Creator/Last-op PIDs --------
shmid      owner      cpid       lpid      
1277952    weekens    3642       3746      
2523137    weekens    4046       4119      
1409026    weekens    3696       3343      
786435     weekens    3203       1310      
1802244    weekens    3887       3919      
1900549    weekens    3899       3343      
1998854    weekens    3906       3343      
2031623    weekens    3872       498       
2326536    weekens    3885       17493     
2228233    weekens    3885       17493     
2261002    weekens    3885       17493     
2424843    weekens    3872       498       
2555916    weekens    3885       17493     
136708109  weekens    3872       498       
2719758    weekens    4176       3343      
2752527    weekens    4176       3343      
2850832    weekens    4573       18066     
2949137    weekens    4155       788       
2981906    weekens    4155       788       
3112979    weekens    4916       4916      
3145748    weekens    4916       4916      
3178517    weekens    4916       4916      
3211286    weekens    4916       4916      
3244055    weekens    4916       4916      
3276824    weekens    4916       4916      
3309593    weekens    4916       4916      
3342362    weekens    4916       4916      
3375131    weekens    4916       4916      
3407900    weekens    4916       4916      
3440669    weekens    4916       4916      
3473438    weekens    4916       4916      
3506207    weekens    4916       4916      
3538976    weekens    4916       4916      
3571745    weekens    4916       4916      
3604514    weekens    4916       4916      
3637283    weekens    4916       4916      
3670052    weekens    4916       4916      
3702821    weekens    4916       4916      
3735590    weekens    4916       4916      
3768359    weekens    4916       4916      
3801128    weekens    4916       4916      
3833897    weekens    4916       4916      
3866666    weekens    4916       4916      
3899435    weekens    4916       4916      
3932204    weekens    4916       4916      
3964973    weekens    4916       4916      
3997742    weekens    4916       4916      
4030511    weekens    4916       4916      
4063280    weekens    4916       4916      
4096049    weekens    4916       4916      
4128818    weekens    4916       4916      
4161587    weekens    4916       4916      
4194356    weekens    4916       4916      
4227125    weekens    4916       4916      
4259894    weekens    4916       4916      
4292663    weekens    4916       4916      
4325432    weekens    4916       4916      
4358201    weekens    4916       4916      
4390970    weekens    4916       4916
.... 4916 PID all the way down
```

, so the process with PID 4916 turned out to consume all the shared memory (it was IntelliJ IDEA). After killing this process, the problem was solved.